# Check if slide number is automatically changing

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When I insert slide numbers in PowerPoint they change automatically if I add or remove a slide. But if I change slide number manually in one of the slide number shapes this shape does not change automatically anymore. I would like to know is there a VBA property to check will slide number be changing automatically or not?

Comment: No, there is no indicator in VBA for whether inheritance for the slide number is broken or not. If you delete the slide number, then replace it, inheritance will be fixed and the correct slide number will display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
currentSlide.DisplayMasterShapes = True
currentSlide.HeadersFooters.Clear
currentSlide.HeadersFooters.Footer.visible = msoTrue
currentSlide.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.visible = msoTrue
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a workaround. But the answer to my question is that there is no such VBA property.